# postgres - convert .dat.gz file .sql file?

Tags: database, postgresql, dump, dbeaver

i received many .dat.gz files from a pg_dump at a postgres database.
i would like to convert it to a .sqli file to import it in a software like dbeaver.
Is there a way to do this? Unfortunately I can't find the answer by googling.

thanks

Comment: You have to ask the producer in which format the dump is, and you certainly cannot convert it to an SQL script that works with DBeaver.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, if as I suspect  it was created using `pg_dump -Fd` then it can be converted to plain text SQL using  `pg_restore -f some_plaintext.sql`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The script will contain `COPY` statements mixed with data, which only `psql` can handle, right?

Comment: Yeah, it looks that is a permanent TODO [COPY stdin](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/8994).  Maybe the OP is in luck and the `pg_dump` was done with `--inserts`:). Or use `pg_restore -s -f `some_plaintext_data.sql` to get the schema in and figure out how to get the data another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the below as suggestions and test before using in production.

At a guess is was some form of `pg_dump -Fd ...` per [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html).

If that is the case and all the files are there you can either do:

`pg_restore -f dump.sql /dat_dir`

which will create a plain version of the dump or:

`pg_restore -d some_db -C /dat_dir`

which will restore directly. In this case using `-d` to connect and then `-C` to create the database that was dumped.

For more information see [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html)

Comment: I used "CREATE DATABASE some_db;" before despite the "-C" option

Comment: Yeah you can manually create the database and then restore directly into it by doing: `pg_restore -d some_db /dat_dir` . When using `-C` the `-d db` is just the database the initial connection is made to before the `CREATE DATABASE ...` command is run.